# Why is my TabView getting messed up when launching the app the first time?

Tags: iphone, xcode, swiftui

when I install the app whether through Xcode or the AppStore, launching it the first time messes up the TabView like this:
[image: Messed up TabView]

Then all I have to do is restart the app and the TabView shows up properly:

[image: Correct TabView]

The purchase view simply contains some text and buttons, and below is the code for the AccountViewController (the TabView):

```
import SwiftUI

struct AccountViewController: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            PurchaseView(btnVisibility: false)
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Purchase", systemImage: "cart")
                }
            BalanceView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Balance", systemImage: "esim")
                }
            SettingsView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Settings", systemImage: "gear")
                }
        }
    }
}
struct AccountViewController_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AccountViewController()
    }
}
```

Tested with multiple iPhones (11, 11 Pro, 13, 14 Pro & 14 Pro Max) and using Xcode Version 15.0 (15A240d)

Edit: Reddit told me it seems like a bug, so I sent a Feedback to Apple they wanted screenshots, sent the screenshot and been waiting for a month with no update.

Edit2: Created a new project, copy-pasted the same files and got the same result, messed up TabView upon first launch.

Edit3: The AccountViewController is being loaded from the LoginView using this line:

```
.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isActive, content: AccountViewController.init)
```

Edit4: `isActive=false` when the view is loaded, LoginView has a Login button, when clicked, it'll send the username & password to a server which returns either `True` or `False`, if `True` then `isActive=true`:

```
Button(action: {
    loadData(){ (results) in
    self.results = results
    if (results[0].lResult == "true"){
        isActive = true
        self.hideKeyboard()
    }
    else{
         isActive = false
    }
}){
  Text("Login")
}
.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isActive, content: AccountViewController.init)
```

Comment: Is `AccountViewController` being loaded as a subview to something else? The "wrong" view would be used if the `TabView` is a view that doesn't take up the whole screen. It can be embedded in another view (a common one is to have the app root, `ContentView` by default, as a direct parent). If you've got it in, say, a `VStack` (or an implicit stack – where there's a second child view within a `body`) you might see what you're experiencing here

Comment: Set an explicit TabViewStyle, the default is automatic and it seems like it is picking page but a default looking TabView must be at the top of the view heierchy

Comment: @ScottM it's being loaded using ```.fullScreenCover``` (Edit3)

Comment: @loremipsum I tried ```.tabViewStyle(.page)``` and on first launch, it was messed up, restarting the app made it come up as pages correctly

Comment: Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead of bits of code and comments.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine that was actually the full code in the ```AccountViewController```, but I'll still follow the minimal code guide, create a new app and try to re-produce the issue.

Comment: It could be that the animation inherent in rendering `fullScreenCover`'s transition on to the screen may be confusing the SwiftUI layout engine. You don't include how `$isActive` is managed; a difference between first launch and subsequent launches might include that variable's starting state?

Comment: @ScottM I've updated the question with ```$isActive``` code (couldn't add it here due to formatting)